# How can I simulate an environment where BitConverter.IsLittleEndian is the opposite for my unit tests?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, endianness

I am using the two methods `BitConverter.GetBytes` and `Array.Reverse` to read and write binary data from a file due the endianness.

My unit tests are passing and the implementation seems fine.

How can I simulate an environment where `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` is the opposite for my unit tests?

Comment: Bwahahahahaha... You can't :-) But it is a great question! Even using Fakes, you would have to rewrite so many methods to simulate it...

Comment: What you should do: create a wrapper class around BitConverter that accepts the parameter "required endianness" and has internal a flag containing the `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` that can be "manipulated" externally by unit tests. This class implements all the needed methods of `BitConverter`, and if `requiredEndianness == savedIsLittleEndian` then it directy uses `BitConverter`, else it uses `BitConverter + Array.Reverse`. You write the unit tests for this class and live happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand my comment: you'll need to use IoC (Inversion of Control) to inject a `BitConverterEx` instance where you need it. This class has a single "parameter": the endianness of the output `byte[]` that it will read/write.

In the end this problem is similar to the common problem "how can I mock `DateTime.Now`"

In the unit tests, instead of injecting a `BitConverterEx` you can inject the `ManipulableBitConverterEx` where you can control the processor flag. Or more correctly you should unit test independently the `BitConverterEx` and your classes, so that when you test your classes, you know that the results of `BitConverterEx` are correct.

```
public class BitConverterEx
{
    public bool ProcessorLittleEndian { get; protected set; }
    public bool DataLittleEndian { get; protected set; }

    public BitConverterEx(bool dataLittleEndian)
    {
        ProcessorLittleEndian = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian;
        DataLittleEndian = dataLittleEndian;
    }

    public byte[] GetBytes(int value)
    {
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);

        if (DataLittleEndian != ProcessorLittleEndian)
        {
            Array.Reverse(bytes);
        }

        return bytes;
    }

    public int ToInt32(byte[] value, int startIndex)
    {
        if (DataLittleEndian == ProcessorLittleEndian)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(value, startIndex);
        }

        byte[] value2 = new byte[sizeof(int)];
        Array.Copy(value, startIndex, value2, 0, value2.Length);
        Array.Reverse(value2);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(value2, 0);
    }
}

public class ManipulableBitConverterEx : BitConverterEx
{
    public ManipulableBitConverterEx(bool processorLittleEndian, bool dataLittleEndian)
        : base(dataLittleEndian)
    {
        ProcessorLittleEndian = processorLittleEndian;
    }
}
```

Note that if you need to reuse many times this class, `Array.Reverse` could be "slow". There are solutions to invert the endianness of data types that manipulate the single bytes using shift, or, xor, ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I think that this is a great solution :)